# Accessing known headers for HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage and HttpContent

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently working with creating a HttpRequestMessage and making a request with it. I have a collection of headers that I want to add to the request message.

I iterate through these headers and add them to the request with

```
message.Headers.Add(header, values);
```

However as part of my testing I'm finding that I get the following error thrown occassionaly (e.g. with Content-Length or Content-Type).

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
>   HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
>   content headers with HttpContent objects.

I've used a decompiler to look at HttpContentHeaders and HttpRequestHeaders and they both have an internal static method that populates a HashSet with a list of known headers, e.g.

```
internal static void AddKnownHeaders(HashSet<string> headerSet)
{
  headerSet.Add("Allow");
  headerSet.Add("Content-Disposition");
  headerSet.Add("Content-Encoding");
  // snip...
}
```

Is there a way to access the known/allowed headers for each of the types (content, request)? Reflection is an option but I'm wondering if there's another method to know where to add the headers?

Comment: [`HttpHeaders.AddWithoutValidation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204926)?

Comment: @CodeCaster for some reason I'm only seeing TryAddWithoutValidation() but that still prevents me adding unknown headers, without throwing an exception. I could catch those that couldn't be added and add them to HttpContent.